# Using system proxy in NSStream

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsurlconnection, nsstream

I'm using `[NSStream getStreamsToHost:port:inputStream:outputStream:]` to create a new stream to a web server to stream generated data on the fly. How would I go about setting up the `NSStream` to use the system HTTP proxy like `NSURLConnection` does? I can't find any info on how to lookup the system proxy, so far all I've discovered is how to setup a known SOCKS proxy against the stream.

Thanks,
J

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer:**

- I have not tried this myself, yet.
- I am a novice to using the `NSStream`/`CF(Read|Write)StreamRef` APIs.

With that out of the way, the way to go *appears* to be using the `SystemConfiguration`-framework — namely the function `SCDynamicStoreCopyProxies`.

This function returns a `CFDictionaryRef`, which can then be set as the stream's `kCFStreamPropertyHTTPProxy`-property (any other proxy type should work by using the protocol's equivalent key).

I don't know yet, whether it is imperative to set this property on the CoreFoundation-level or if using `-[NSStream setProperty:forKey:]` is possible, as well — I strongly assume the latter, but again: I more or less started seriously looking into these APIs *today*…

Anyway, there's a section called [*"Navigating Firewalls"*](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Networking/Conceptual/CFNetwork/CFStreamTasks/CFStreamTasks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001132-CH6-SW1) covering this stuff in Apple's [CFNetworking Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Networking/Conceptual/CFNetwork/Introduction/Introduction.html)—which describes this more detailed.

---

### Update

In case anyone is still interested in this, there's an API which I managed to **not** find, the whole weekend.

On iOS, the `SCDynamicStore` APIs (which are referred to in the link I posted) do not exist. There is, however, *another* API which has been around since iOS 2.0 and is present on OS X since 10.6:

`CFProxySupport`

Although `CFProxySupport` is part of the `CFNetwork` framework, it isn't mentioned anywhere in the "CFNetwork Programming Guide" — which is a shame because it's simple and pleasant to use.

Filed a bug with Apple's docs (rdar://problem/10491759)